# Window.open() is opening in a new tab in safari

Tags: javascript

I am using window.open to open a modal pop up its opening as modal popup in chrome and ie but in safari its opens as a new tab please help!!.

```
var popUpObj;
    function showModalPopUp()
    {
    popUpObj=window.open("PopUp.htm",
    "ModalPopUp",
    "toolbar=no," +
    "scrollbars=no," +
    "location=no," +
    "statusbar=no," +
    "menubar=no," +
    "resizable=0," +
    "width=100," +
    "height=100," +
    "left = 490," +
    "top=300"
    );
    popUpObj.focus();
    LoadModalDiv();
    }
```

Comment: maybe put it inside a onclick to have it work on safari? - `<div class='btn' onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");'>Open google search</div>` - but I saw some people say that you need to use `var newTab = safari.self.browserWindow.openTab();` for safari

Comment: i tried but still its opening in a new tab instead of window